# Scikit Learn Random Forest Classifier Hyperparameter Min Target Sample Size

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, sampling, hyperparameter

From reading the docs on Scikit Learn, I haven't been able to find an answer, but does anyone know if there is a way to specify to always include a specific number out of the max sample size of samples where the answer is true?

For example:

Lets say I set my max sample size as 50 per tree, but out of the 50, I want it to alwayd have 15 of those be true, where as the other 35 are false.

This would be pulled from my already split dataset.

I would appreciate any input into this, thanks.

Comment: I'm having a hard time thinking of the practical utility of this. Can you describe a bit more why you think this might be valuable?

Comment: My dataset is heavily imbalanced, so I would like each tree to include most of the target samples. I believe by continually including these target samples in each tree, the RFC will learn from my target samples, rather than having little to no samples where they are true values.